# Questions about efficiency of estimators with longitudinal data

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, consistency, clustered-standard-errors, efficiency

I'm modelling data with repeated observations; I'm reading up on options and pitfalls, and have a few questions.

1. Coefficient estimates are still unbiased and consistent in the presence of heteroscedasticity and clustering, so is the motivation for standard errors just for efficiency?
2. With clustering, estimates are no longer BLUE, if we use clustered (or any other kind of robust standard error, in their respective use cases) are they now BLUE?
3. fGLS models the variance of the squared residuals, how does this compare to sandwich estimators? I was wondering, because fGLS leads to constant variance of the squared residuals, are they are more efficient?
4. I've also found GEE and mixed models, how do these compare in terms of efficiency vs clustered estimators.
5. In non-Gaussian GLMs and mixed model non-Gaussian GLMs, I have read coefficients may be biased and inconsistent with repeated observations. I have found proofs showing that this is not the case for OLS, but I've been unable to find proofs that show biasedness and inconsistency in the GLM mixed model GLM setting. Would a proof have to involve a specific distribution, or can it be shown generically?
6. Is there are any reference aside from Greene (if it is recommended), that will help with the maths behind the answers to these questions

Thanks